# Pandas nested groupby gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working on a problem where I am using a nested groupby.apply on a pandas DataFrame. During the first apply I am adding a column that I am using for the second inner groupby.apply. The combined result looks faulty to me. Can anyone explain to me why the below phenomen happens and how to reliably fix it?

Here is a minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T = np.array( [
        [1,1,1],
        [1,1,1],
        [1,2,2],
        [1,2,2],
        [2,1,3],
        [2,1,3],
        [2,2,4],
        [2,2,4],
])

df = pd.DataFrame(T, columns= ['a','b','c' ])

print(df)


def foo2(x):
    return x

def foo(x):

    print("*" * 80 )

    # Add column d and groupby/apply on column 'd'
    x['d'] = [1, 1, 2, 2]
    x = x.groupby('d').apply(foo2)

    print(x)

    print("*" * 80)
    return x


# Apply first groupby/apply on column 'a'
df = df.groupby('a').apply( foo)

print("*"*80)
print("*"*80)

print(df)
```

When I run the above code on my Windows laptop I get the expected result

```py
     a  b  c  d
a              
1 0  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  2  1  2  2  2
  3  1  2  2  2
2 4  2  1  3  1
  5  2  1  3  1
  6  2  2  4  2
  7  2  2  4  2
```

Running the same code on a Mac gives

```py
     a  b  c  d
a              
1 0  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1
  2  1  2  2  2
  3  1  2  2  2
2 4  1  1  3  1
  5  1  1  3  1
  6  1  2  4  2
  7  1  2  4  2
```

The issue here is that in column 'a' the last 4 entries are 1 while they should be 2 as on the Windows machine.

EDIT:

Pandas version on both: 0.24.2

Python version on Windows: 3.7.3

Python version on Mac: 3.7.4

Comment: Please post pandas versions on both, as well as python versions

Comment: Thanks, I made the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mac, Python: 3.6.8]

My thinking is that the expected behaviour of nested `DataFrame.apply`s are going to be a little convoluted to debug. My recommendation is to cut-to-the-chase by emulating what you want to achieve from `apply` (i.e. map then reduce):

1. Map: Use python's native `map` method, followed by
2. Reduce: Use `pandas.concat` to combine the results

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def my_apply(df, f):
    return pd.concat(map(f, df))

def foo(x):
    group, grouped = x
    grouped['d'] = [1, 1, 2, 2]
    return grouped.groupby('d').apply(lambda x: x)

T = np.array([[1,1,1]]*2 + [[1,2,2]]*2 +
             [[2,1,3]]*2 + [[2,2,4]]*2)           
df = pd.DataFrame(T, columns= ['a','b','c' ])
df = my_apply(df.groupby('a'), foo)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  2  2  2
3  1  2  2  2
4  2  1  3  1
5  2  1  3  1
6  2  2  4  2
7  2  2  4  2
```

Notes:

1. I have not tried to address the difference in implementation/architecture leading to this performance difference between Mac/Windows]
2. I've minified your example, replaced `foo2` with a `lambda`, feel free to swap back.
3. The above code will throw the following warning `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame [...]`. This is because we're *deliberately* setting a value of a copy. This is expected behaviour, not a bug. Unfortunately `pandas` interprets this operation as a mistake, since it probably normally is.

Comment: Hey thanks, The code throws the following warning. Maybe this is related to why pandas fails: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  grouped['d'] = [1, 1, 2, 2].

Comment: I've added a note about the (expected) warning. You can disable it, but the 'real' way around it is to make a copy of the `grouped` object using `grouped.copy()`, but for large dataframes that won't be very performant, so I thought it would be best to make do with the warning. I would very much doubt that this is related to the problem in the question. My best guess would be that the group index is getting absorbed somewhere along the way in the Mac version of pandas. In practice, the apply and group by methods were likely not meant to be operated on in this way.